# Retriving the attachment's address,which is encoded in base64 from odoo 12 database(postgres)

Tags: odoo-12

I have a web app and i need to display an image whose address is stored in odoo database(postgre) and is encoded in base64.
Can anyone help me in how i can decode the data and get the link.
Below is an example.
The data is like this in the database
[image: Database Image]

I want to decode the data to get the url which look like this:[image: URL image as it is in odoo website]

Comment: Or is there a way i can display my product images on my web app based on the product id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths for partner image in v12 are:

- /web/image?model=res.partner&field=image_medium&id=**partner_id**&unique=**nonce**
- /web/image/res.partner/**partner_id**/**image_name**?unique=**nonce**

Where:

- **partner_id** is the id of the partner in Odoo database.
- **nonce** is optional, is used to avoid cache and can be current timestamp.
- **partner_name** can be anything

The problem with this urls is that public or portal users can't access any partner data by default for privacy reasons except from themselves (including the image). Depending on your case, some solutions could be:

- If you aren't concerned about privacy issues, install website_partner module, publish partners one by one, and the urls will return the real image.
- create a module with a controller that delivers only the partner image using sudo().